# Magento renderers empty

Tags: attributes, ce-1.9.0.1, renderer

I have the following line my `configurable.phtml`

```
$_renderers = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getSortedChildren()
```

But this throws the following error:

```
Call to a member function getChild() on a non-object
```

When I remove `->getSortedChildren` the code works but the default swatches aren't displayed, instead there are dropdowns.

```
if(!empty($this->getChild('attr_renderers'))):
    $_renderers = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getSortedChildren();
endif;
```

If I use this nothing is displayed, which means that there are no child objects (I believe)

```
$_renderers = $this->getChild('attr_renderers'); 
var_dump($_renderers);
```

This returns `bool(false)`. How can I fix this that the attribute swatches are displayed again?

Comment: Have you checked that you have a child block defined in your XML layout update for `attr_renderers` under your current block?

Comment: @musicliftsme i'm not really that familiar with the layout, in what direction should I be looking?

Comment: Are you on CE 1.9 and using `rwd`?

Comment: @musicliftsme CE 1.9 indeed but a custom template but it's very similair to the rwd template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using CE 1.9+ (or EE equivalent) and `rwd` or an inherited package/theme of it. This is happening because `$this->getChild('attr_renderers')` doesn't return anything. It leads me to believe that your child block `attr_renderers` is not defined in the layout XML, which should be the the file below, for this page, `configurable.phtml`. In the original XML file, this is all defined.

```
app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/catalog.xml
```

Find the section that looks like below and make sure the `attr_renderers` child block, nested under `configurable.phtml`, is defined.

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers" as="attr_renderers" />
    <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.after" as="after" />
</block>
```

Try it out.